# GnuPG - connecting to specific card reader when multiple reader available

Tags: gnupg, smartcard, openpgp

Currently I can use

```
$ gpg --expert --card-status
```

to interact with smartcards that run the OpenPGP applet. Through trial-and-error, it seems that only the first card reader will interact with `gpg`. Using options that pass to `scdaemon` seem to be deprecated:

```
$ gpg --reader-port  1 --card-status
gpg: WARNING: "--reader-port" is an obsolete option - it has no effect except on scdaemon
```

Is there a way to interact with an OpenPGP smartcard that is not connected to the first card reader?

**Edit**: After some more research, I found a blog post from the author of the libccid library https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2019/06/gnupg-and-pcsc-conflicts.html that mentions:

> ### Tell GnuPG to use PC/SC
>
> Another solution is to make GnuPG and pcscd collaborate to work together. Luckily it is possible to do that using
> the scdaemon option `--disable-ccid`
>
> From the documentation:
>
> ```
> --disable-ccid
>
>   Disable the integrated support for CCID compliant readers. This  
>   allows falling back to one of the other drivers even if the internal  
>   CCID driver can handle the reader. Note, that CCID support is only  
>   available if libusb was available at build time.
> ```
>
> With this option
> scdaemon will use PC/SC to talk to the smart card and the conflict is
> solved.
>
> It is possible to tell scdaemon to always use this option by editing
> the scdaemon configuration file. By default it is
> `~/.gnupg/scdaemon.conf` and it should contain the line:
>
> ```
> disable-ccid
> ```

**Edit 2**: With these configuration adjustments:

`$HOME/.gnupg/scdaemon.conf`

```
pcsc-driver /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcsclite.so.1
disable-ccid
reader-port <reader-string>
```

I'm able to restart the agent with `systemctl --user restart gpg-agent.service` in order to use the different reader. This works!

Is there any way to pass the reader option to `gpg` or the `scdaemon` instead of editing a on-disk file & restarting? If a shell script is needed, is it possible to send a signal instead of file/restart workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this instruction into `$HOME/.gnupg/scdaemon.conf`, not pass it directly to gpg.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, this configuration file does not exist by default. In spite of that, I can connect to an OpenPGP card if it is in the first smartcard reader slot. (Not the second, or any other).

Comment: I'm able to get the second reader accessed by editing the `scdaemon.conf` & restarting the agent. Is there way to pass this option at runtime using the CLI?